# Maven build failure from missing tycho dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, tycho

I'm attempting to build two Maven projects from Eclipse. One project constitutes a set of dependencies and libraries to be used for the other project which contains  all of my source code. Both are configured as Maven projects using Tycho 1.0.0 .

I have a parent POM file that contains three modules: a folder containing my target file, the plugin containing the dependencies and the plugin that contains the source code. When trying to maven build on the parent POM, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.0.0:compile (default-compile) on project com.ericsson.cd-editor.ui: Execution default-compile of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.0.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.0.0:compile: freemarker/template/Configuration
```

Gonna post the full error log in pastebin since it's diffcult to read in a Stack Overflow post:

http://pastebin.com/EYnsqvpJ

Here is my parent POM file:

http://pastebin.com/wSAtwspV

I've been told by a colleague of mine that the reason this might be happening is that this dependency might be used by Tycho and cannot be found. The freemarker package is however available in my .m2/repository/.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell where the error might be.

First, make sure the jar you have in your m2 archive actually contains the class the compiler is looking for.

You could check whether you dependencies are in the central maven repository, instead of making a project containing them.

Does the project that needs all the dependencies state them explicitly, e.g., in feature.xml or Manifest.mf? Otherwise tycho will not load them, even if they are accessible to maven.

Posting the pom.xml files for the modules might be helpful. Hope you'll figure it out :)